# Apostol: Prove $\frac{1}{k}\int_0^x R(t)\sinh{(k(x-t))}dt$ is particular solution to $y''-k^2y=R(x)$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The following is from Apostol's *Calculus*, Volume I, Section 8.17, Problem 18

> If $k$ is a nonzero constant, prove that the equation $$y''-k^2y=R(x)\tag{1}$$
> has a particular solution $y_1$ given by
>
> $$y_1=\frac{1}{k}\int_0^x R(t)\sinh{k(x-t)}dt\tag{2}$$
>
> Find the general solution of the equation $y''-9y=e^{3x}$.

My first thought was to differentiate (2) twice to get $y_1''$ and plug it and $y_1$ into (1) and check that we get an identity.

I ended up solving the problem another way (probably the intended way), but **my question is** how do we actually do what I had first thought to do? So, first of all, how do we calculate $y_1''$? Then, if we plug that in to (1) together with $y_1$ can we reach an identity?

Note that I copied (2) above exactly as it is written in the book.

The $\sinh$ inside the integral is $\sinh{(k(x-t))}$ (at first the lack of parentheses seemed ambiguous, but after solving the problem I was able to figure this out).

Here is my solution to this problem, for reference

The characteristic equation for $y''-k^2y=0$ is

$$r^2-k^2=0$$

and so we have the real roots $\pm k$.

$v_1(x)=e^{kx}$ and $v_2(x)=e^{-kx}$ are two independent solutions to the homogeneous equation.

The Wronskian of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is

$$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
e^{kx} & ke^{kx}\\
e^{-kx} & -ke^{-kx}
\end{vmatrix}= -2k\tag{3}$$

There is a theorem that shows us how to obtain a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation (1) from two independent solutions to the homogeneous equation.

Such a particular solution looks like

$$y_p(x)=t_1(x)v_1(x)+t_2(x)v_2(x)\tag{4}$$

where

$$t_1(x)=-\int v_2(t)\frac{R(t)}{W(t)}dt\tag{5}$$

$$t_2(x)=\int v_1(t)\frac{R(t)}{W(t)}dt\tag{6}$$

Subbing in $v_1$ and $v_2$ and simplifying we eventually reach (2), thus proving the desired result.

Comment: Start with $\sinh (A+B)=e^{-A}\sinh B+e^{B}\sinh A$.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the solution is
$$
y(x)=\int_0^xF(x,t)\,dt.
$$
As the $x$ occurs two times, you get two terms in the derivative
$$
y'(x)=F(x,x)+\int_0^x\partial_{(1,0)}F(x,t)\,dt
$$

Now note that with
$$
F(x,t)=R(t)\frac{\sinh(k(x-t))}{k},
$$
we get that $F(x,x)=0$, so the first term falls away.

Similar principles apply to the second derivative
$$
y''(x)=\partial_{(1,0)}F(x,x)+\int_0^x\partial_{(2,0)}F(x,t)\,dt
$$
and $\partial_{(1,0)}F(x,x)=R(x)$.

---

One could also consider the helper function
$$
h_a(x)=y(x)\cosh(k(x-a))-\frac1ky'(x)\sinh(k(x-a))
$$
This has derivative
$$
h_a'(x)=\frac1k\sinh(k(x-a))(k^2y(x)-y''(x))=-\frac1k\sinh(k(x-a))R(x)
$$
so that finally
$$
y(a)=h_a(a)=\int_0^ah_a'(x)\,dx=...
$$